# Explorer (проводник) написанный на c#

Tags: c#, windows

Для своего проекта мне нужен полноценный аналог проводника Windows (Explorer). Написать самому довольно трудоемко. Хотела найти на просторах интернета, но нормального варианта что бы выглядел открывал папки и файлы, (делал предпоказ файлов) и отображал значки файлов так и не нашла.
Может кто сталкивался с таким аналогом, киньте в меня ссылкой

Comment: На всякий даю ссылки на то что я нашла:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2672/My-Explorer-In-C - можно только полистать файловую систему, но сами файлы открыть нельзя
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/activate-account?rp_d=70%2frjowSqsoFypYPk00%2fFg%3d%3d - виснет ужасно так и не дождалась когда загрузится.

Comment: Зачем вам обязательно на C#?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows API Code Pack](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1)

Explorer, если не ошибаюсь, обитал в пространстве `Shell`

Comment: Кстати, интересная [вещь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeeTEwCnfSk), спасибо за наводку.